# Problems with jQuery History Plugin, or easier to use alternative?

Tags: ajax, history.js

I am trying to get my AJAX .load function to have back/reload/bookmark capability.
I am using the jquery plugin history.js.

My content is being loaded in my content div from another html file using anchor points within that to specify which div to select the information from (depending on link clicked).

Currently, i have managed to get the plugin to change the address but the back/reload functionality is not working.

This is the plugin code i am using: https://github.com/balupton/jquery-history/blob/master/scripts/jquery.history.js

Head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="back.js"></script>
```

Navigation:

```
<div id="leftnav">
        <p class="leftnavtext">
            <a class="navlinks" id="about2" href="#/about">ABOUT</a> <br>
            <a class="navlinks" id="process2" href="#/process">PROCESS</a> <br>
            <a class="navlinks" id="materials2" href="#/materials">MATERIALS</a> <br>
            <a class="navlinks" id="pricing2" href="#/pricing">PRICING</a>
        </p>
```

AJAX Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#about2").click(function(){
    $("#content").load("content.html #about");
});
  $("#process2").click(function(){ 
    $("#content").load("content.html #process");
 });
  $("#materials2").click(function(){ 
    $("#content").load("content.html #materials");
});
  $("#pricing2").click(function(){
    $("#content").load("content.html #pricing");
 });
   $("#pricing3").click(function(){
    $("#content").load("content.html #pricing");
});
   $("#infinite1").click(function(){
    $("#content").load("content.html #infinite");
});


});
```

back.js Code (path.js is the plugin.):

```
function nav_event(hash) {
  // Some sort of navigation happened, update page
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $.history.init(nav_event);
  $.history.load('#/about');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $.history.init(nav_event);
  $.history.load('#/process');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $.history.init(nav_event);
  $.history.load('#/materials');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $.history.init(nav_event);
  $.history.load('#/pricing');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $.history.init(nav_event);
  $.history.load('#/infinite');
}
```

Can anyone see where im going wrong with this? Or can they suggest a better plugin to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match('MSIE')!=null) {return false;} /*prevent IE crash*/

    window.addEventListener("popstate",   function(e) {window.location = lastURL;  });

    window.history.pushState({"html": newURL,"pageTitle": newURL},"", newURL);
```

I stole this from another answer.
Unfortunately it does not work in IE.

further reading:

http://html5doctor.com/history-api/

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: Cheers, i have managed to get the url state to change, but after further reading on on the history-api information it mentions that if the address (with hashbang) is pasted into a new browser window it should open the ajax'd page. But still no luck.